# how to change firebase account in a flutter project?

Tags: flutter, firebase

I created a flutter project with my personal firebase, but now the client has already created his firebase, how do I change the account in a project, I've searched the documentation but without success?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its very simple,
just type this

```
firebase login --reauth
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is no easy way to switch.

The information you configured when you first created flutter project on firebase, it has be configured again with clients Firebase.

For example -> replace old GoogleService-info.plist, android package name and iOS bundleID with the new one.

Answer (score 1):

```
// Change Firebase project.
// May require `firebase login` to access the project.

firebase use MYPROJECT

// Update Flutter configuration based on project. 
// --yes will overwrite the configuration.

flutterfire config \
  --project=MYPROJECT \
  --out=lib/firebase_options_dev.dart \
  --android-package-nam=com.myandroid.id \
  --platforms=web,android --yes

// In case of using glocud, switch the project, too.
// May require `gcloud login` to access the project.

gcloud config set project MYPROJECT
```

**Note**

Some parameters of FlutterFire are optional, Flutterfire will try figuring out the correct values. Check all parameters with `flutterfire --help config`.